# Monitoring a task in apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I start spark master using : ./sbin/start-master.sh
as described at : 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

I then submit the Spark job :

```
sh ./bin/spark-submit \
  --class simplespark.Driver \
  --master spark://`localhost`:7077 \
    C:\\Users\\Adrian\\workspace\\simplespark\\target\\simplespark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

How can run a simple app which demonstrates a parallel task running ?

When I view http://`localhost`:4040/executors/ & http://`localhost`:8080/ there are no
tasks running :

[image]

[image]

The .jar I'm running (simplespark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) just contains a single Scala object :

```
package simplespark

    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

    object Driver {

      def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf()
          .setMaster("local")
          .setAppName("knn")
          .setSparkHome("C:\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4")
          .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g");

        val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
        val l = List(1)

        sc.parallelize(l)

        while(true){}

      }
    }
```

Update : When I change `--master spark://`localhost`:7077 \` to `--master spark://Adrian-PC:7077 \`

I can see update on the Spark UI :

[image]

I have also updated Driver.scala to read default context, as I'm not sure if I set it correctly for submitting Spark jobs :

package simplespark

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object Driver {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    System.setProperty("spark.executor.memory", "2g")

    val sc = new SparkContext();
    val l = List(1)

    val c = sc.parallelize(List(2, 3, 5, 7)).count()
    println(c)

    sc.stop

  }
}
```

On Spark console I receive multiple same all same messages :

```
14/12/26 20:08:32 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

So it appears that the Spark job is not reaching the master ?

Update2 : After I start (thanks to Lomig Mégard comment below) the worker using :

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://Adrian-PC:7077
```

I receive error :

```
14/12/27 21:23:52 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20141227212351-0003/8 removed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\cygdrive\c\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/compute-classpath.cmd" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
14/12/27 21:23:52 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20141227212351-0003/9 on worker-20141227211411-Adrian-PC-58199 (Adrian-PC:58199) with 4 cores
14/12/27 21:23:52 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20141227212351-0003/9 on hostPort Adrian-PC:58199 with 4 cores, 2.0 GB RAM
14/12/27 21:23:52 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20141227212351-0003/9 is now RUNNING
14/12/27 21:23:52 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20141227212351-0003/9 is now FAILED (java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\cygdrive\c\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/compute-classpath.cmd" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified)
14/12/27 21:23:52 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20141227212351-0003/9 removed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\cygdrive\c\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/compute-classpath.cmd" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
14/12/27 21:23:52 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: Master removed our application: FAILED
14/12/27 21:23:52 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: Master removed our application: FAILED
14/12/27 21:23:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from Stage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at Driver.scala:14)
14/12/27 21:23:52 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
```

I'm running the scripts on Windows using Cygwin. To fix this error I copy the Spark installation to cygwin C:\ drive. But then I receive a new error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Master removed our application: FAILED
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start the actual computation to see the job.

```
val c = sc.parallelize(List(2, 3, 5, 7)).count()
println(c)
```

Here `count` is called an action, you need at least one of them to begin a job. You can find the list of available actions [in the Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions).

The other methods are called [transformations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations). They are lazily executed.

Don't forget to stop the context at the end, instead of your infinite loop, with `sc.stop()`.

**Edit:** For the updated question, you allocate more memory to the executor than there is available in the worker. The defaults should be fine for simple tests.

You also need to have a running worker linked to your master. See [this doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) to start it.

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://IP:PORT
```

Comment: thanks but I don't think your answer solves my issue, please see question update. I'm using your suggestion sc.stop

Comment: Are you sure you have a worker with enough memory? Try to remove the `spark.executor.memory` configuration. With this simple example the default is enough. And indeed, the `localhost` cannot be used as a master. You need to specify the real host name.

Comment: Removing spark.executor.memory does not have any effect. I think this issue may be due to fact that I'm running locally on Windows & executing submit scripts using Cygwin. I will update when test on a proper UNIX environment.

Comment: Are you sure you have a worker running by the way? See my updated answer.

Comment: I did not have a worker running. please see question update. I think this issue may be related to Cygin intallation

Comment: Indeed it seems to be linked to Cygin. I don't use Windows thus I will be of poor help. You can use a VM or a container (Docker for example) with a Linux distrib.